# How to publish IIS Application from VisualStudio?

Tags: iis

I'm looking to publish automatically by using `Publish` in VisualStudio my C# Application, **so it's not a WebSite** but it's a `IIS` Website application.

When using `Publish` profile and Publish to publish a website all works fine, but i can't get on how i can setup the `Web Deploy` to deploy a WebSite Application...

As by right clicking the application i have only import/export under Deploy while only the Website has "Configure Web Deploy Publishing" ...

Answer (score 0):

Web Deploy simplifies deployment of Web applications and Web sites to IIS servers, and must be installed as an application on the server. you can refer to this link about how to configure the required settings for Web Deploy. [Publish to a Web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-a-web-site?view=vs-2019#publish-to-a-web-site)